# Is there any better way to get source marker on "popupopen" event in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

So this is how I do it now:

```
 map.on('popupopen', ({ popup }) => {
  if (popup instanceof L.Popup) {
    const marker = popup._source as L.Marker;
  }
});
```

I really don't like accessing private variables in leaflet. I still have not found in leaflet api clean method to get marker that is binded to active popup.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popupevent

Comment: @IvanSanchez so no better way?

Comment: Read the documentation. The event handler function is passed an object which you're destructuring; which properties are available in that object?

Comment: popup, sourceTarget, target, type @IvanSanchez

Comment: ...and what does the documentation say about `sourceTarget`?

Comment: sourceTarget in my case is instance of map

Comment: Yes, behaviour as expected, since you're doing `map.on(...` instead of `marker.on(...`.

Comment: Well I don't have access to marker, I need to target marker that have popup opened in that moment.  Mapping over all markers is really not solution, marker have getPopup but popup does not have getMarker.

Comment: Iterate through all markers, or have them in a `L.FeatureGroup`, then. The source of the map's `popupopen` event will always be the map itself.

Comment: lol @IvanSanchez.  But srsly, @Nenad, you can learn a lot from this dude.  Personally I think its fine to grab the `popup._source` variable. Its meant to be private, but there's really no such thing in pure javascript. As long as you're careful, its the most direct way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is to emit new event on marker popupopen and access it from wherever you want.

```
popupopen: () => {
  map.fire('someevent', { somemarker });
},
```

```
map.on({
  'someevent': (event) => {} // <- event has marker
});
```